# Calling a function pointer with Emscripten

Tags: javascript, emscripten

With Emscripten, is it possible to call a function pointer (thus, a number) from JavaScript?
The signature of the function is variable, so I can't write a helper and be done.

To illustrate an example, I've got a function like this:

```
// Returns a function pointer to call, with the appropiate
// arguments, to initialize the demanded feature.
void* get_feature_activator(feature_t feat);
```

You're supposed to use it as follows:

```
// Initialize the speaker
void* activator = get_feature_activator(FEATURE_SPEAKER);
// We know this function needs one float, so we cast and call it
((void(*)(float))activator) (3.0);
```

To do the same with JavaScript:

```
var activator = _get_feature_activator(constants.FEATURE_SPEAKER);
// TODO: Need to call this pointer with one float
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call a C function pointer from JS using `Runtime.dynCall`. See for example

https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/ee17f05c0a45cad728ce0f215f2d2ffcdd75434b/src/library_browser.js#L715

The arguments are `(type signature, pointer, array of arguments)`. For example, the type 'vi' means return void, receive one integer parameter. This corresponds to FUNCTION_TABLE_vi which you can see in the generated code.

Comment: Whoa! I had seen this functions before and I knew you could use them to call a pointer, but... I thought they were roman numerals xD

Comment: So how can you use dynCall to invoke a function that takes a function as an argument? For example, a function that takes a function that takes a string. Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a C function:

```
void call_feature_activator(int activator, float in_val) {
  ((void(*)(float))activator) (in_val);
}
```

You can then call the function on the JavaScript side to trigger your activator call and it will handle casting back to a function pointer and calling it.

Comment: As I said, I can't use a helper because the signature isn't fixed. In that case, the function accepted one float, but for another feature it can accept two ints, etc.

Comment: Is there a way to call a function pointer without having to create a C function for each possible signature?