# Call C++ function pointer from Javascript

Tags: javascript, c++, emscripten

Is it possible to pass function pointers from C++ (compiled into Javascript using Emscripten) to directly-written JS? I've found ways of creating function pointers of Javascript functions to pass to C++, but not a way of exposing a function pointer, given a value at runtime in C++ code, to Javascript.

Code-wide, what I'm after is to be able to complete the code snippet below in order to call the function passed as `cFunctionPointer` where I'm doing the `console.log`

```
void passToJs(void (*cFunctionPointer)()) {
  EM_ASM_ARGS({
    // Prints out an integer. Would like to be able to
    // call the function it represents.
    console.log($0);
  }, cFunctionPointer);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/25584986/1319998. You can use the `Runtime.dynCall` function:

```
void passToJs(void (*cFunctionPointer)()) {
  EM_ASM_ARGS({
    Module.Runtime.dynCall('v', $0, []);
  }, cFunctionPointer);
}
```

The `'v'` is the signature of a void function that doesn't take any arguments.

Apparently it supports other signatures, such as `'vii'`, which is a void function that takes 2 integer arguments. The integer arguments would then have to passed in the array which is the 3rd argument of `Runtime.dynCall`.