# Pass pointer to std::vector to Javascript using Emscripten, and use it

Tags: javascript, c++, emscripten

I would like to create a `std::vector` (specifically, a `std::vector<string>`) in C++, and then pass it (or rather, a pointer to it) to Javascript, in order to be able to access its data/functions from directly-written Javascript.

So far I can get the integer pointer:

```
vector<string> myVector;
myVector.push_back("First item");
myVector.push_back("Second item");

EM_ASM_ARGS({
  // Prints out an integer value of the pointer,
  // but I would like to access the object members/data 
  // of myVector
  console.log($0);
}, &myVector);
```

I have found information at http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/api_reference/bind.h.html#register_vector__cCP and http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/embind.html#built-in-type-conversions about the `register_vector` function

```
#include <emscripten/bind.h>
EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(Wrappers) {
  register_vector<std::string>("VectorString");
};
```

which can be used to create a new vector from the Javascript world:

```
var myVector = new Module.VectorString();
```

but I can't figure out how to use this to access vector that already exists in the C++ world.

If I try to use `Module.Runtime.dynCall('v', $0, []);` on the pointer, as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/29319440/1319998 when passing function pointers, then I get an error:

`Invalid function pointer '380' called with signature 'v'`

I have tried a few different combinations of signatures, and they all seem to fail (Which I'm not really surprised about: it's not really a function pointer I'm calling, but a pointer to an instance of an object)

Comment: I've edited this question to explain why it's not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/29319440/1319998 . The solution there doesn't apply in this case: that was calling a C++ function pointer from Javascript, while this question is about is accessing members of an existing C++ object.

Comment: I've also edited the title of the one at http://stackoverflow.com/a/29319440/1319998 (it's my question) to hopefully better show why it's different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `reinterpret_cast` trick from https://stackoverflow.com/a/27364643/1319998 you can add another constructor to the object returned from the `register_vector` factory that does nothing but converts an integer pointer to a `vector<string>`:

```
vector<string> *vectorFromIntPointer(uintptr_t vec) {
  return reinterpret_cast<vector<string> *>(vec);
}

EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(Wrappers) {
  register_vector<string>("VectorString").constructor(&vectorFromIntPointer, allow_raw_pointers());
};
```

Then if you create a vector in C++ code, you can access in JS code by

- Getting a pointer to it
- Passing the pointer to JS code via `EM_AMS_ARGS`
- In the JS Code, create a new `Module.VectorString` object passing in the pointer value to the constructor

As in the following code:

```
vector<string> myVector;
myVector.push_back("First item");
myVector.push_back("Second item");

EM_ASM_ARGS({
  var myVector = new Module.VectorString($0);
  // Prints "Second item"
  console.log(myVector.get(1));
}, &myVector);
```

Comment: Where is the documentation for *.get* function,How did you find this get function for myVector? Please post a link thnx.

Comment: Five years later... the `get` method is added by `register_vector`, see `emscripten/bind.h`